# Python Tkinter error when calling method from menu bar option

Tags: python, tkinter, menubar

I get the following error when running the display method defined in the Page1 class from the Display option on the menu bar:

```
 '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'body_frm'
```

The method works correctly when run from the Display button in Page1.

I created an instance of Page1 called self.page1. This is used to call the method from the menu bar:

```
file_menu.add_command(label='Display', command=lambda: self.page1.display(self))
```

I think there may be something wrong here as I'm using lambda and `display(self)`.

With just `command=self.page1.display`, I get the following error: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'page1'

With `lambda: self.page1.display`, I don't get an error but the method doesn't work
With `lambda: self.page1.display()`, I get TypeError: display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

The call from the page button uses `command=self.display` and works fine.

I can get the method to function both on the menu bar and page button by change `self.body_frm` to `Page1.body_frm`. While this works, I don't believe that's a proper implementation.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Method Test')
        self.geometry('500x300')

        # Create frame container
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create menu bar
        self.create_menu_frame(self)

        # Create a dictionary of frames
        self.frames = {}

        self.page1 = Page1
        self.page2 = Page2

        # Add the two page frames to the dictionary.
        for page_frame in (self.page1, self.page2):
            frame = page_frame(container, self)
            self.frames[page_frame] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        # Switch Order Entry frame
        self.show_frame(self.page1)

    def create_menu_frame(self, container: ttk.Frame) -> None:
        # Create menu bar
        menu_bar = tk.Menu(container)

        # Create options for File menu
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(
            label='Display', command=lambda: self.page1.display(self))
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(
            label='Page 1', command=lambda: self.show_frame(self.page1))
        file_menu.add_command(
            label='Page 2', command=lambda: self.show_frame(self.page2))
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.quit)

        # Assign file menu list to the File option
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

        # Assign assign menu bar to the window
        container.config(menu=menu_bar)

    def show_frame(self, cont: tk.Frame) -> None:
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        # Raises the specified frame to the top
        frame.tkraise()


class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        Page1.result_str = tk.StringVar(value='')

        # Create page frame sections
        self.header_frm = tk.Frame(self)
        self.header_frm.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.header_frm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.body_frm = tk.Frame(self)
        self.body_frm.pack()
        self.body_frm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.footer_frm = tk.Frame(self)
        self.footer_frm.pack()
        self.footer_frm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Header Section
        label = tk.Label(self.header_frm, text='This is the Main Page')
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        # footer Section
        close_btn = tk.Button(self.footer_frm, text='Close', command=quit)
        close_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        display_btn = tk.Button(
            self.footer_frm, text='Display', command=self.display)
        display_btn.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        switch_window_btn = tk.Button(
            self.footer_frm, text='Page 2',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(controller.page2)
        )
        switch_window_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    def display(self):
        label = tk.Label(
            self.body_frm,
            text='Display method works')
        label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=5)


class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Second Page')
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        switch_window_button = tk.Button(
            self,
            text='Return to Page 1',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(controller.page1),
        )
        switch_window_button.pack(side='bottom', fill=tk.X)


def main():
    prog_app = App()
    prog_app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You assign `self.page1` *after* calling `self.create_menu_frame()`, so you can't use that attribute in the method.  Note that `self.page1 = Page1` is not actually creating an instance of your class, it's just making an alias for the class itself.

Comment: I moved the ```self.create_menu_frame()``` so its after the page assignments. I'm still getting the same error,  ```'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'body_frm'```

Comment: How would I create an actual instance of the Page1 class. Specifying the parent and controller is tripping me up. In the current code, I'm able to execute some of the display method  code. I added a ```print('Accessed display method')``` statement to verify this. When the method is called via the menu bar, the label doesn't seem to see self.body_frm as being it's parent widget. The error seem to indicate that self body_frm is being define in the Page1 class. However, the print statement displays as intended.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code

```
command=lambda: self.frames[self.page1].display()
```

or

```
command=lambda: self.frames[Page1].display()
```

---

`self.page1` is not instance of class but only alias for `Page1`.

Real instance is in `self.frames[self.page1]` (or `self.frames[Page1]`)

Comment: I went with the second option and removed the ```self.page1``` alias as it did not add anything to the code.